# Update facebook status using pyfacebook offline access

Tags: python, facebook

I'm trying to update a user status from a django python app.
The user went thru facebook connect and registers to the app.
I got sessionkey and fbuid.

```
  fb = Facebook(FACEBOOK_API_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY)

    if fbsessionkey:
        fb.session_key = fbsessionkey 
        fb.uid = fbuid
        fb.auth.createToken()
        fb.auth.getSession()
        #update the facebook status
        fb.users.setStatus(status="testing",clear=False)
    else:
        pass
```

What am i doing wrong? im getting:

```
Error 104: Incorrect signature
```

Please note the user already granted offline access also.
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add signature. It is MD5 hash of the current request and your secret key. I was mistaken about the issue first sorry :p
Please check http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.setStatus and know about how to get the signature